Function keys not working unless I switch user logout and re-login again
LOGITECH G915 (TKL keyboard)
So, the story is like this:
I was tweaking the keyboard configuration thru "special" programs, not gnome, like autokey and others, and now function keys are not working anymore...

I have trying resetting keyboard configuration, layout, everything....

I already tried dconf reset -f /org/gnome and dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration


Now the only workaround I have to get the FN keys working again is this:

login to a 2nd user (created before and untouched, unused user) that still has the FN keys running,
logout,
switch back to my user.

Voila, that makes the "trick" to have them working again...

I've run xev, evtest and showkey, FN keys are never detected unless I do the "workaround" after which are detected again in the 3  programs..

I've already uninstalled some daemons and programs that I needed to customized a 2nd keyboard (keypad)...

I've compared the daemons running in both users with service --status-all, and systemctl | grep  "running" just in case there was some daemon modifying things... but before and after the workaround: the system processes are the same

I've inspected my ~/.config folder and it doesn't differ from the 2nd user

I also upgraded from Ubuntu 20.x to Ubuntu 22.04.5 to no avail..


Clues:

It might be something in my user?, and I cannot dispose of it,
It might be related to X server ? gnome doesn't seem to be having the bad configuration held after switching users
After restart, If I login to the 2nd user, the FN keys work well, and keep functioning when switching to my 1st user... SO it's only a configuration defect from my 1st user...

I only have 1 keyboard: Logitek G915 TKL, when configuring from command line, I select the only closest? keyboard in the list: Logitech G15 extra keys via G15 daemon
Computer: Asus P50N (minibox, not a laptop)
Ubuntu 22.04.5 LTS
Gnome version: 42.9


You should post this as an answer instead of as an edit to your question. After a few days, you can then mark your answer as the accepted solution.

it was the solaar program I installed to configure Logitech receivers, this little evil daemon has something like "profiles", and it was in a different profile without much conf. (whatever)
Anyway, Solaar is a pretty cool program, please dont punish it
